# How to mock document.currentScript to return a valid script object with data attributes

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to write some tests in jest for an API that is intended to be shared with third parties. The inclusion method used by the third parties is a script tag which initiates the script but also passes along some data attributes via document.currentScript.

Here is a very cut down version of the code with the relevant parts:

```
// clientLib.js
export const getCurrentScript = () => document.currentScript;

export const initLib = () => {
  const currentScript = getCurrentScript();
  const reference = currentScript.getAttribute('data-reference');
  const lang = currentScript.getAttribute('data-lang');

  return new clientLib(reference, lang);
}

export class clientLib {
  constructor(reference, lang) {
    this._brand = reference;
    this._market = lang;
  }
}

window.clientLib = initLib();



// html

<script src="clientLib.js" data-reference="12345" data-lang="en-GB"></script>
```

What I'd like to be able to do in my test is something like this, but I've been unable to get anything to work:

```
// clientLib.test.js

import {
  getCurrentScript,
  initLib,
  clientLib
} from './clientLib';

// here I want to mock the output of getCurrentScript() since document.currentScript does 
// not exist, and I need the mock to return a script object with the two data attributes
// (ideally I need to be able to recreate this mock with both, either or none of the attributes)
// to test other cases

describe('initLib', () => {
  it('returns a new instance of the library based on script attributes', () => {
    window.clientLib = initLib();
    // in here I should then be able to access properties on my lib on the window object
  });
});
```

I did manage to get this working using an external setup file but for logistical reasons I don't think I can use this approach. I've tried to mock it in the test file itself and keep coming back to an "Invalid variable access: document" error. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?